# relative url not work in cloud front AWS

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I am using AWS service for my project and project is in PHP and use linux server in it.

when i include file like this :

> include('../Models/ConDB.php');

is display '**failed to open stream: No such file or directory**' and throws 500 error.

is AWS EC2 instance not supported like this??

please help me how to make it supportable..

Comment: Check where you are with `echo getcwd();`.

Comment: located at : /var/www/html/my-folder

Comment: `../` means to go 1 directory up. I guess it is `/Models/ConDB.php`?

Comment: ok .. understand... Thankyou

Comment: My delight. Have joy.